# NSDateFormatter is not working in ios 8.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdateformatter, utc

I have to convert date as **UTC** formate. I got **nil** value in date object. It's working for all other ios versions except ios **8.0** Please help me out this..

```
NSString *ValidDateUtc_=@"7/7/2015 5:00:00 AM";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss a"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:ValidDateUtc_];
```

Comment: Do you get an error or something?

Comment: No. I got only **nil** value.

Comment: hmmm... works fine exactly as written for me on iOS 9 beta

Comment: Yes. It's working fine all other except ios 8.0

Comment: Works for me iOS 8.4

Comment: Are you using break point to check the date value, I suggest you to put `NSLog` statement.

Comment: iOS 8.4 is working fine. It's not working iOS 8.0. I tried with NSLog also. I didn't get any solution for that.

Comment: is [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"] work?

Comment: @RemingHsu It's not working...

Answer (score 0):

OK i try it with this dateFormat "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss aa" and its working fine.

If you still getting nil , try changing timeZone , or locale

```
dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name:"UTC") or NSTimeZone(name:"GMT")
dateFromatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "your country identifier")
```

Comment: It's showing error as "Use of undeclared identifier 'named'".

Comment: The question is tagged Objective-C, not Swift.

Comment: Ok am not very familiar with objective-c , its not hard to translate it and is two lines of code